# Rails Setting up unique integration environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environments

I am trying to setup a unique environment (but effectively a new development environment so that various global parameters can be different).  I've followed lots of examples to create a new environment (I used my development config as the starting point).

My new environment is singleserverintegration.

- a new environment.rb
- added new logic to initializers/additional.rb (elsif Rails.env.eql?("singleserverintegration"))
- added entries to database.yml

BUT when-ever i attempt to setup the environment

```
RAILS_ENV="singleserverintegration" && rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate
```

I get a

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Capybara
```

why is it pulling out test configuration (which is where capybara is used as part of rspec) [i've noticed that additional.rb has capybara config reguardless of the environment, but it never complains when i run rake / db commands for my dev environment. why would it complain now?]

what am i missing - guidance appreciated for a relative newbie...

thanks

Ben

bottom line of additional.rb is

```
Capybara.server_port = 8066
```

but, this does not cause an issue when i setup development environments!?

Answer (score 0):

try adding your new env to the capybara gem as well

Ex:

```
group :test, :development, :singleserverintegration do
  gem 'capybara'
end
```